# XSL XAML unique names

Tags: xaml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I try to make a XAML file using XSL, and one of the things I need is a unique name for 100 textblocks. I create the Textblocks in a for-each loop (which works, all the elements are created) and then try to use position() to give each a unique name:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//value">
    <xsl:element name="TextBlock">
    <xsl:attribute name="x:Name" select="'number_txt_',position()"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Grid.Row" select="position()+2"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Grid.Column" select="0"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Text" select="./@number"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="FontSize" select="20"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Foreground" select="'Ivory'"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="HorizontalAlignment">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Center'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="VerticalAlignment">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Center'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, this gives me this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="number_txt_ 1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="1" FontSize="20"
             Foreground="Ivory"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="number_txt_ 2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="2" FontSize="20"
             Foreground="Ivory"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

and so on for all the TextBlocks. Note the whitespace between "number_txt_" and the digit.

I want to use this file in a C# silverlight project, but that doesn't allow whitespaces in a x:Name, nor does it allow a single digit (I've tried it with only the counter, doesn't work). 
Does anyone have any ideas? I know some of you are going to suggest a counter, but my knowledge about that is very small. 
I thank you, for taking the time to read my problem, and hope you can think of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace this**:

```
<xsl:attribute name="x:Name" select="'number_txt_',position()"/>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:attribute name="x:Name" select="concat('number_txt_',position())"/>
```

**Additionally, this whole fragment**:

```
<xsl:element name="TextBlock">
<xsl:attribute name="x:Name" select="'number_txt_',position()"/>
<xsl:attribute name="Grid.Row" select="position()+2"/>
<xsl:attribute name="Grid.Column" select="0"/>
<xsl:attribute name="Text" select="./@number"/>
<xsl:attribute name="FontSize" select="20"/>
<xsl:attribute name="Foreground" select="'Ivory'"/>
<xsl:attribute name="HorizontalAlignment">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Center'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="VerticalAlignment">
<xsl:value-of select="'Center'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

**can be re-written in a much shorter and understandable form**:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="number_txt_{position()}" Grid.Row="{position()+2}" 
           Grid.Column="0" Text="{@number}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Ivory"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```